# CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s)

Tags: installation, conda, malformed

I'm getting a Malformed version string error with my conda.  I have no idea how to debug this or how to check it.

Can anyone help?  GitHub has talked about the issue but I haven't seen any fixes.

```
-bash-4.1$ conda install -c bioconda pysam
Solving environment: failed



 1. CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s).
```

In response to the comment below:

```
(mage_env) -bash-4.1$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/mage_env/bin:/usr/local/packages/jdk-8u121/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/rrichter/local/bin:/home/syooseph/utils/clustalw1.83:/usr/local/packages/gsl/bin:/usr/local/sge_current/bin/lx-amd64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/Dropseq/:/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/Dropseq/Drop-seq_tools-1.13/
(mage_env) -bash-4.1$ conda info

     active environment : mage_env
    active env location : /usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/mage_env
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/jespinoz/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/jespinoz/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.2.final.0
       base environment : /usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/ursky/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/ursky/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda/pkgs
                          /home/jespinoz/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda/envs
                          /home/jespinoz/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.2 Linux/2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64 centos/6.4 glibc/2.12
                UID:GID : 3456:63
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Hi @merv I've added the conda info.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This [looks like it was fixed with Conda 4.6.0](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/7780). Upgrading your Conda should resolve the issue.

```
conda upgrade -n base conda
```

If you have trouble solving environment, I suggest trying

```
conda upgrade -n base -c defaults --override-channels conda
```

This will exclude all other channels during the solving process, and helps because having too many options to prune is one of the main reasons for slow solves.

Comment: I've been running it for a few hours and it keeps solving :( `Solving environment: /`

Comment: Try `conda upgrade -n base -c defaults --override-channels conda`. This will turn off the `bioconda` and `conda-forge` channels temporarily for this install.

Comment: When I use the command: `conda upgrade -n base -c defaults --override-channels conda` It gave warning `A newer version of conda exists` and asks to use `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` when I run this command I go back to the same error in the main question.

Comment: @Medhat that latter suggestion is only if you're having solve troubles. It sounds like you have a different issue (can't upgrade Conda), so search for that, or ask a new question.

Comment: This issue is quite terrible. Currently, the only solution is to fresh install conda with python version >= 3.6: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8732. How could someone make an API breaking change that broke even the possibility of upgrading conda...?

Comment: Is there an alternative workaround when I don't have root permission to upgrade conda?

Comment: @hertzsprung Not really. Let your sys admins know that they should upgrade Conda. Otherwise, this really comes from PyPI packages that have `~=` dependencies. So, avoid using `pip` in your Conda envs. If you must, then you would have to manually edit the offending packages to remove the `~=`, e.g., replacing it with `>=`, but you'd need to do this on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: you can add a new environment and install all your libraries again using conda

Comment: can someone explain what if I do not have the permission to do the update on base environement. I only want to resolve the problem on the environment I am working as a non-root user?

Comment: @AZiZASaber use Micromamba

Answer (score 2):

I needed to remove `conda-forge` from my .condarc file.  Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem

`conda upgrade -n base conda`

did pull the latest version but did not make the upgrade as I did not clear my previous install properly before installing latest anaconda.

Removing /root/anaconda3 ( default installation folder in my case ) &
removing /root/.conda & reinstalling the latest anaconda

Post that

`conda upgrade -n base conda`

would help you upgrade to 4.16+ version ( as of today, its latest )

One Additional Step which one must follow if they are importing env from one machine to this one:

remove specific version from conda package dependency, example here:

> https://gitlab.com/mkuhring/TaxIt/-/commit/a8587e41bfff4c3362556c1c46d23d99ac3af069

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with conda 4.8.2 while I tried to create an environment from a yaml file.

loading a different, already existing environment and unloading it again did the trick in multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error also when trying to install a package to a personal directory on an HPC, as in:

```
$ conda install -c dranew shapeit 
Solving environment: failed
CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s).
```

As a user of the HPC I'm not in control of the version of conda installed so had to find another solution.

This ended up working:

```
$ conda create --name shapeit -c dranew shapeit
```

or in generic terms,

```
$ conda create --name <packagename> -c <conda_channel_name> <packagename>
```

This tells conda to create an environment named packagename, then find the package in its channel (dranew for shapeit, bioconda for OP) and install it in that new environment.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I ran this code when inside my .conda/envs directory.

Hope this helps someone else!