# Q:CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s)

Tags: anaconda

I solved the problem as follows：
[CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084960/condavalueerror-malformed-version-string-invalid-characters)

but upgrading Anaconda had the same problem,
The error picture is as follows:

[image: 1]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade conda --user pip
```